# Numpy: How to get the index of a tuple within an array of tuples using 'where()'

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, tuples

Existing answers for this question all involve tuples of uneven length, which is a problem I don't have, so their solutions are not relevant to me.

I have a 1d array of tuples. I want to get the index of a given tuple within that index.

```
a = numpy.array([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
b = numpy.where(numpy.all(a == (1, 2), axis = 1))
```

almost works, but I don't understand why the shape of the array it returns is [3,] rather than just [3]. It means I have to use b[0][0] rather than just b[0] to get my desired index.

`a === (1, 2)` yields

```
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

So I would have assumed using `.all(axis = 1)` on this would give a 1D array of bools, one element for each row.

Comment: _"I have a 1d array of tuples"_: No you don't, you have a regular 2d array. The shape of the returned array is `(3,)` because that is how a single-element tuple is represented. In python, `(3)` is the same as `3`. The comma is necessary to denote that the parentheses actually indicate a tuple

Comment: As for why your `b` is a _tuple_ containing a single array, read the [docs of `np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), since `np.where(a)` is shorthand for `np.asarray(a).nonzero()`